# How to get item ID under "INTERESTS"

Tags: facebook-page

I am developing an application to get images from the specific Facebook page registered under "INTERESTS" node displayed in the left menu area of the top page.

So I want to get the ID of the menu item under "INTERESTS".

I can find a way to get "Interests" of user's profile, but it is different from "INTERESTS".

Please someone let me know how to get it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I tested it with a new list of my own. If I copy the link address and query the Graph API for the id it contains, I get something like this,

```
{
  "id": "…",
  "name": "test",
  "list_type": "user_created",
  "type": "friendlist"
}
```

But I can not see it under /me/friendlists, no luck finding a connection somewhere using FQL either. Can’t tell if it’s not showing up because the type is "user_created" (maybe?) …